# PHP cross-domain SOAP request

Tags: php, soap

I am new to php, and am trying to write a script to send a cross-domain SOAP data request and then pass the response to javascript to present on my page.  I understand that I need to use SoapClient, but am not sure how to implement this correctly.

```
<?php 

$client = new SoapClient("http://ofmpub.epa.gov/WATERSWebServices/SpatialServices?WSDL", 
                            array('latitude'             => 46.852783,
                                  'longitude'            => -114.004517,
                                  'search_radius_miles'  => 5,
                                  'programs_list'        => "303D",));

$result = $client->waters.spatial_services.get_entities_by_lat_long;

echo "return_code= " . $result;
?>
```

The documentation for this service is [here](http://www.epa.gov/waters/geoservices/docs/get_entities_by_latlong_service.html). Am I on the right track? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the testing of this script.

Comment: You realize you can't can't make a cross-domain request on a service that do not implement CORS, right?

Comment: When it is PHP doing the request, there is no such thing as "cross-domain".